# Difference between a proposition and an assertion

Tags: terminology, propositional-calculus

It may be a silly doubt, but let me ask this.

> What is the difference between a proposition and an assertion?

I know there's a very thin line between  the two terminologies, but I'm unable to get that.

Comment: Why the downvote?

Comment: A closevote for migration to meta. Mystifying.

Answer (score 10):

There is a subtle difference between the two:

1. A *proposition* is a statement in either a natural or a formal language, for which it makes sense to ask whether it is either true or false.
2. An *assertion* is a statement which one claims to be true.

As such, assertions are more restrictive than propositions. For example:

1. In a logic textbook, we read "It's raining" as an example of a proposition. This is not an assertion.
2. I look out of the window and say: "It's raining." From the context, it is clear that I am asserting this proposition to be true. Hence, it is an assertion.

The distinction is fine, because everything that is a proposition can also be an assertion, while all assertions are necessarily propositions. So the distinction between the two depends entirely on the context.

Comment: Though whenever I start a paragraph with **Proposition.**, that is certainly something I claim (or assert) to be true (and usually show to be true right away), but neither deserves the merit to be called **Theorem.** nor is it so subordinate that it should be called **Lemma.** instead :)

Comment: @Hagen A fair point :). I'd edit it into my answer if it weren't already obvious from the tags that OP is talking about logic rather than mathematical practice.

Comment: @Lord, Hagen.. thanks! But can you clarify with an example.?that would be very helpful

Comment: @UjjwalSaini How careless of me not to include one. Here you go.

Comment: @Lord_Farin...this is what i was looking for! nice example, now i got this..thanks :D

Comment: @UjjwalSaini You're welcome. Since you are new, you may not be familiar with the procedure when questions are answered -- see [this topic](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers) from the help centre.

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen, some people classify their proven assertions into lemma/theorem/corollary, others just call everything a proposition. Mostly a matter of taste.

Comment: This is exactly I have been looking for hours. Thank you @Lord_Farin. After the **prover confirms something about proposition, it becomes assertion** to them and but still can be true or false to the challenger. I mean what if the challenger sees sunny weather through windows after they are told Its raining. In that case the assertion is false. So assertion is subject is based on beliefs of the prover.

Comment: Also you missed full-stop in the first statement. Does that mean something special? Because grammatically if it is a statement, it must end with full-stop.

Answer (score 4):

An assertion is a proposition that is claimed to be true.

Proposition P1:  *The tree is tall*
(This might be true or might be false, and it can be just an idea proposed for consideration, apart from anyone's actual beliefs. It may be thought or expressed.)

Assertion A:  "The tree is tall."
(This might be true or might be false, but it is a statement of a proposition claimed to be true. Generally, someone purports to believe it and offers it as fact.)

The assertion is itself equivalent to a proposition (P2) *about* proposition P1:

A = P2:  *P1 is true*.                                              (P2 is the assertion of P1.)

Answer (score 0):

- Both are statements.
- For a Proposition, we can say whether it is true or false.
- But for an assertion, no chance to be false and definitely it is true.
- So you can identify that all assertions are prepositions also.
- But all propositions should not be assertions.

Comment: it's my understanding that an assertion is a statement whose maker claims to be true, and the maker could be wrong.

Comment: Exactly, its up to challenger to prove it true or false. There is a proof by assertion, where prover forces its assertion again and again until there is no challenge to prove it otherwise. It's interesting to look into it.